# github basic authentication with javascript (Appcelerator)

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, github-api

My issue is I believe I've constructed the request correctly, but I am getting [400 {"message":"Problems parsing JSON"}]

here is my code:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function() {
             Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

            json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            callback(json);
        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            alert('error!');
            Ti.API.info(e.error + " " + this.status + " " + this.responseText);
        }
    });

    xhr.validatesSecureCertificate = true;
    xhr.open("POST", "https://api.github.com/authorizations");
    xhr.setTimeout(10000);
    authstr = 'Basic ' + Titanium.Utils.base64encode(User.username + ':' + User.password);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authstr);
    xhr.send({username: User.username, password: User.password});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply missed the JSON.stringify method.... on my body :P. Thanks!